# Delete media from cloud storage after X hours

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I have 2 categories of media on my Firebase Storage Bucket located in separated folders. I would like firebase deleting the media of a single folder after 24h since the upload date.
Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built into Firebase/Cloud Storage for this, so you will have to build it yourself.

Since the `metadata` for each object contains a [`timeCreated` property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.FullMetadata#timecreated), you can [get a list of files](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects#storage-list-objects-nodejs), then check the metadata of each file, and delete the file if it expired.

If you get stuck while implementing this recipe, post a new question with the minimum code that reprocues where you got stuck.